# Why can't I accept all hosts for my Rest Assured POST method?

Tags: java, ssl, https, apache-httpclient-4.x, rest-assured

- Our target server (censored.local) has HTTPS certificate with CN = censored.com, *.censored.com
- The test raises an exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Certificate for 
"censored.local" doesn't match any of the subject alternative 
names: [censored.com, *.censored.com]
```

- I understand why this happens (RFC 2818) but I would like to bypass this for testing purposes. It is not possible to install a different certificate on the target server.
- .relaxedHTTPSValidation() and .allowAllHostnames() did not work. So, I tried to code my way into this:

My test class:

```
...
.given().spec(reqSpec)
...
```

My configuration class:

```
public abstract class Configurator {
    protected static TestEnv envConf = chooseEnv();
    protected static RequestSpecification reqSpec;
    static { try { reqSpec = configureRestAssured(); } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); } }

    protected static TestEnv chooseEnv() {
        // Some logic following to select an instance from TestEnv (not shown here)
        ...    
        envConf = TestEnv.BETA;
        return envConf;
    }
    protected static RequestSpecification configureRestAssured() {
        RequestSpecification reqSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder().build();
        reqSpec
                .header("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", envConf.getBearerToken()))
                // This gets the censored.local URI:
                .baseUri(envConf.getBaseURI())

                .config(getRAconfig());
        return reqSpec;
    }
    private static RestAssuredConfig getRAconfig() {
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocket = getSSLsocket (envConf.getKeystoreFile(), "keystorePassword", "PrivateKeyPassword");
        RestAssuredConfig raConfig = RestAssuredConfig.config()
        .sslConfig(SSLConfig.sslConfig().sslSocketFactory(sslSocket));
        return raConfig;
    }
    private static SSLSocketFactory getSSLsocket(String ksPath, String ksPassword, String pkPassword) {
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream(ksPath), ksPassword.toCharArray());
        SSLContext context = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadKeyMaterial(keystore, pkPassword.toCharArray(), firstPrivateKeyStrategy())
                .loadTrustMaterial(trustEveryoneStrategy())
                .build();
        return new SSLSocketFactory(context);
    }
    private static PrivateKeyStrategy firstPrivateKeyStrategy() {
        return new PrivateKeyStrategy() {
            @Override
            public String chooseAlias(Map<String, PrivateKeyDetails> aliases, Socket socket) {
                return aliases.keySet().iterator().next();
            }
        };
    }
    private static TrustStrategy trustEveryoneStrategy() {
        return new TrustStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                    throws CertificateException {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }}
```

- I don't know if it helps, but during debugging, I can see:

```
raConfig = {RestAssuredConfig@2752} 
 configs = {HashMap@2753}  size = 17
  ... 
  {Class@2003} "class io.restassured.config.SSLConfig" -> {SSLConfig@3257} 
   key = {Class@2003} "class io.restassured.config.SSLConfig"
   value = {SSLConfig@3257} 
    pathToKeyStore = null
    pathToTrustStore = null
    keyStorePassword = null
    trustStorePassword = null
    keyStoreType = "pkcs12"
    trustStoreType = "pkcs12"
    port = -1
    trustStore = null
    keyStore = null
    x509HostnameVerifier = {StrictHostnameVerifier@3286} "STRICT"
```

Is STRICT basically showing my problem?
If so, how to hack a not-STRICT x509HostnameVerifier?

- Also, I am aware of the following, but no idea how to use this for my Rest Assured connections: https://tutoref.com/how-to-disable-ssl-certificat-validation-in-java/

Comment: `X509HostnameVerifier` is for checking if a hostname matches the names stored inside the **server's** (not **client's**) X.509 certificate: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/X509HostnameVerifier.html Can you check if the Subject in the server certificate matches the actual server domain. E.g. with Web browser: https://www.shellhacks.com/get-ssl-certificate-from-server-site-url-export-download/

Comment: The other thing is that usage of `SSLSockerFactory` may overwrite setting in your `SSLConfig` REST-assured class. This is because configuration from SSLConfig is used only if `SSLSockerFactory` has not been provided. See: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/adea885dd97dd977a6e7b142b560577404b7811f/rest-assured/src/main/groovy/io/restassured/internal/TrustAndKeystoreSpecImpl.groovy#L47-L52

Comment: @dzieciou I was wondering today if I can somehow get the actual server certificate, lol! I will check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the way to customize the SSL configuration to do as I need. 
Slightly censored code attached. Look for the "holy grail" comment:

```
 protected static RequestSpecification configureRestAssured() {
    // Create the ReqSpec instance:
    RequestSpecification reqSpecToBuild = new RequestSpecBuilder().build();
    // Configure more simple stuff for common request specification:
    reqSpecToBuild
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .baseUri(envConf.getBaseURI())
            .config(getRAconfig());
    return reqSpecToBuild; 
    }
// Add extended config object to the request spec:
private static RestAssuredConfig getRAconfig() {
    // Create a special socket with our keystore and ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER:
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocket = getSSLsocket (envConf.getKeystoreFile(), somePass, somePass);
    // Create a configuration instance to load into the request spec via config():
    RestAssuredConfig raConfigToBuild = RestAssuredConfig.config()
            // Set SSL configuration into the RA configuration, with an SSLConfig object, that refers to our socket:
            .sslConfig(SSLConfig.sslConfig().sslSocketFactory(sslSocket));
    return raConfigToBuild;
}
private static SSLSocketFactory getSSLsocket(String ksPath, String ksPassword, String pkPassword) {
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    // Load keystore file and password:
    keystore.load(new FileInputStream(ksPath), ksPassword.toCharArray());
    SSLContext context = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadKeyMaterial(keystore, pkPassword.toCharArray())
            .build();
    // This is the holy grail:
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketToBuild = new SSLSocketFactory(context, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    return sslSocketToBuild;
}
}
```

Notice how I am not just supplying one argument to the constructor of SSLSocketFactory but I am supplying the regular argument (context) as well as the ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER argument - this makes the difference!